# Is there a tensorflow equivalent to np.empty?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, empty-list

Numpy has this helper function, [np.empty](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html), which will:

> Return a new array of given shape and type, without initializing entries.

I find it pretty useful when I want to create a tensor using [tf.concat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html) since:

> The number of dimensions of the input tensors must match, and all dimensions except axis must be equal.

So it comes in handy to start with an empty tensor of an expected shape. Is there any way to achieve this in tensorflow?

[edit]

A simplified example of why I want this

```
    netInput = np.empty([0, 4])
    netTarget = np.empty([0, 4])
    inputWidth = 2

    for step in range(data.shape.as_list()[-2]-frames_width-1):
        netInput = tf.concat([netInput, data[0, step:step + frames_width, :]], -2)
        target = tf.concat([target, data[0, step + frames_width + 1:step + frames_width + 2, :]], -2)
```

In this example, if netInput or netTarget are initialized, I'll be concatenating an extra example with that initialization. And to initialize them with the first value, I need to hack the loop. Nothing mayor, I just wondered if there is a 'tensorflow' way to solve this.

Comment: No, that wouldn't really make sense in TensorFlow. Tensors are immutable (except variables), so a tensor with undefined values would hardly be useful. How were you thinking of using it with `tf.concat`?

Comment: When preparing data for an LSTM. There is one vector with examples and I need two vectors, one for inputs and another one for predictions. The inputs vector is quite redundant since at each time-step it contains several previous data-points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is create a variable that you do not initialize. If you use `tf.global_variables_initializer()` to initialize your variables, disable putting your variable in the list of global variables during initialization by setting `collections=[]`.

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(np.empty((2, 3), dtype=np.float32), collections=[])
y = tf.Variable(np.empty((2, 3), dtype=np.float32))

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

# y has been initialized with the content of "np.empty"
y.eval()
# x is not initialized, you have to do it yourself later
x.eval()
```

Here `np.empty` is provided to `x` only to specify its shape and type, not for initialization.

Now for operations such as `tf.concat`, you actually don't have (indeed cannot) manage the memory yourself -- you cannot preallocate the output as some `numpy` functions allow you to. Tensorflow already manages memory and does smart tricks such as reusing memory block for the output if it detects it can do so.

Comment: I modified the question to add an example to further clarify what I meant.

Comment: I realized that I was looking for something different. Your answer is correct for my question, but what I was looking for was as simply as using 0 as a dimension in an axis.

Answer (score 6):

If you're creating an empty tensor, `tf.zeros` will do

```
>>> a = tf.zeros([0, 4])
>>> tf.concat([a, [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]], axis=0)
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 4), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
       [5., 6., 7., 8.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Answer (score 6):

In TF 2,

```
tensor = tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor(()), (0, n))
```

worked for me.

Comment: i wonder what the memory usage difference between this and my answer is

Comment: you can even do `tf.reshape((), (0, n))`